# POST http://localhost:3000/auth 400 (Bad Request) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to send register form data to my server, but receive (Bad Request). I test my server with postman & it work correctly with this data:

```
{
    "username": "root",
    "email": "root@gmail.com",
    "password": "Pesho@"
}
```

But have problem with Angular & can't find were is the problem.

This is **register.component.ts:**

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  public registerFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private readonly auth: AuthService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerFormGroup = this.auth.registerFormGroup(this.registerFormGroup);
  }

  public register(username: string, email: string, password: string) {
    this.auth.register(username, email, password);
    console.log({username});
    console.log({email});
    console.log({password});
  }
}
```

This is **auth.srvice.ts:**

```
public register(username: string, password: string, email: string): Subscription {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth',
      {
        username,
        email,
        password,
      })
      .subscribe(
        (success: any) => {
          this.notificator.success(success.message);
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.login(email, password);
          }, 1500);
        }
        ,
        (err) => {
          this.notificator.error(err.error.message);
        }
      );
  }
```

And this is the small html register form - **register.component.html:**

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="this.registerFormGroup"
      (ngSubmit)="this.register(name.value, email.value, password.value)" autocomplete="off">

      <mat-card-content>

        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput #name autocomplete="off" formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control"
          placeholder="Name *">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput #email autocomplete="off" #email matInput class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" type="email"
          formControlName="email">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput #password formControlName="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password *">
        </mat-form-field>

      </mat-card-content>

      <button mat-stroked-button color="accent" class="btn-block" type="submit" value="Sign Up">Register</button>

    </form>
```

I put few console logs to see what the form sends & they are looking correct:

{username: "root"}
username: "root"
**proto**: Object

{email: "root@gmail.com"}
email: "root@gmail.com"
**proto**: Object

{password: "Pesho@"}
password: "Pesho@"
**proto**: Object

I used the same logic in previous project with Bootstrap & it worked perfect. In this case use Material, but I don't think the problem is from there. I didn't receive any errors in NestJS server terminal.

Comment: Can you post your server side code which is receiving the request and Do u receive any CORS error?

Comment: Here is the server side logic - https://pastebin.com/LqSpjrAL. Didn't receive any errors, just in browser console. If put date with postman everything is ok, and user go to DB...

Comment: You are not sending any headers with your post request like `application/json` were you doing the same thing with postman? 

P.S  I never used NestJS so I might not be able to help that much but I'll try.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LWVPUWe I'm still thinking that the error isn't coming from NestJS. The post request is in auth.service.ts

Comment: Try to add this before post request `let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')` then `return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth',
      {
        username,
        email,
        password,
      },{headers: headers})`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sUQRifD post request looking ok.

Comment: So I try to remove UserRegisterDTO & send another post request, but in this time receive error 500 and server down - https://imgur.com/a/RLBh0Yj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the order in which you are passing your arguments

This is your **register.component.ts:**

```
public register(username: string, email: string, password: string) {
this.auth.register(username, email, password); <---- Here you are passing username,email,password
console.log({username});
console.log({email});
console.log({password});
  }
}
```

This is **auth.srvice.ts:** Here you are accepting username,password,email

```
public register(username: string, password: string, email: string): Subscription {
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth',
  {
    username,
    email,
    password,
  })
```

So to fix this switch arguments in either **register.component.ts** or  **auth.srvice.ts**

Comment: Thanks! I found the same thing before 5 minutes after use your advice. The detailed header log direct me to RegisterUserDTO and problem with email. So remove @IsEmail & post status was 201 (OK). I saw in my DB registration with email = password & switch the arguments. Thanks for help :)